# WebSQL throws an error when pouchdb tries to get documents: could not prepare statement (1 too many SQL variables)

Tags: pouchdb, web-sql

WebSQL throws an error when pouchdb tries to get documents by keys: could not prepare statement (1 too many SQL variables)

Answer (score 0):

The WebSQL adapter was [dropped from the default PouchDb build in PouchDb 7](https://pouchdb.com/2018/06/21/pouchdb-7.0.0.html) so it would be worth moving to IndexedDb if that is possible. It might be worth adding your code to the question otherwise it will be difficult for anyone to help further.

Comment: I think those are the two main options, but I am not familiar with alternatives. The PouchDb site has more information: https://pouchdb.com/adapters.html#pouchdb_in_the_browser